# Validating value in NSTextField when bound to Shared User Defaults Controller?

Tags: xcode, macos, validation, swift, interface-builder

How do I hook in validation functions to the value of an NSTextField that is bound to Shared User Defaults Controller? All the tutorials I've found on Key-value Validation bind to the AppDelegate. Do I need to disable "auto submit" and add a submit button and hook in the validation there?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found: 
You only need to assign the **delegate** outlet of the NSTextField and then override **controlTextDidEndEditing** in that delegate.

Comment: That's not a solution. If the user entered invalid input, it will still run the binding even if you manually fail your "validation", whereas proper validation will deny the binding until an appropriate value is entered.

Comment: Use the inherited delegate method `control:textShouldEndEditing:` instead. Then you can reject or modify the value entered by the user before the binding runs.